# Simple wifi-independent way of connecting to pi via ethernet

Tags: networking, dhcp, ethernet-port, static-ip

I've tried everything.

Connecting to the pi once the Pi is connected to a WiFi network is easy. Internet sharing is also easy on OS X. I can't figure out how to make a basic static route between the Pi and my MacBook via ethernet/crossover cable (I have both, but they both work with internet sharing seamlessly).

I've tried setting a static IP in the /etc/network/interfaces file 
... and in the cmdline.txt file

I've tried making the eth0 connection auto with the setting of dhcp, all while following [this](http://www.jacquesf.com/2011/04/mac-os-x-dhcp-server/) guide, but DHCPDISCOVER never ends up working. It's all too confusing, all I want to do is ssh into my Pi after plugging in my ethernet cable, I don't care if it has internet or not.

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/633017/using-macbook-pro-ethernet-as-a-dhcp-server) is wonderful, but IT ONLY WORKS ON MY HOME NETWORK. Doesn't work with a public network where I can't control the DHCP server, so it's not an option.

Does anyone have a simple way I can set up a basic connection between OS X and the raspberry pi without the pi having a wireless card and without relying on OS X's internet sharing option?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. If ALL you want to do is connect from OS X to Pi on a network (your own or someone elses) I suggest you install `netatalk` on the Pi.

This allows you Mac to discover the Pi by name (assuming the network allows peer to peer connections). I have a script which I use on my Mac Replace `NNNNNNN` by your Pi's name.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to start ssh connection to Pi
ssh pi@NNNNNNN.local
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```

---

```
open afp://NNNNNNN.local
```

Will allow you to access Pi with Finder (or a better File Manager e.g. QuollEyeTree).

Connection is much easier if you also set up public keys.